# Replacing values in one column with values in another column

Tags: python, loops, replace

I imported a dataset, but some of the values in the 'platelet' column were added into a new column called 'X', leaving the 'platelet' column with NaNs in their place.

I want to iterate through every entry in the platelet column, and when I hit a NaN value, I want to replace that value with whatever is in the 'X' column. Here's what I tried below (something similar worked perfectly fine in R).

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I get an error that says:

```
TypeError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

< ipython-input-2520-414f4874fae7 > in  < module >()

  3 import math

  4 

----> 5 for i in range(0, N-1):

  6     if math.isnan(data['platelet'][i]):

  7         data['platelet'][i] = data['X'][i]

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

---

```
N = len(data['platelet'])

import math  


for i in range(0, N-1):  

    if math.isnan(data['platelet'][i]):  

        data['platelet'][i] = data['X'][i]
```

Comment: Please give us the full error.  This doesn't look like the complete code.

Comment: Ok, I filled in the whole error, but I don't think there's anything else useful in there.

Comment: Tip: if the range start from zero, you can omit the 0 value. ;)

Comment: Can you add the dataframe initialization? It would be easier to test the code. At least 2 lines.

Comment: Just a guess since the code causing this isn't here, you've used `range` as a variable up above and now you're trying to call it as a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it with the fillna method:

```
data['platelet'] = data['platelet'].fillna(data['X'])
```

This will fill NA values in data['platelet'] with the corresponding value in column X.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely has something to do with your data because when I simulate your scenario it works fine.

Try adding a print statement of your data before iteration, and also between iterations.

Also `for i in range(0, N-1):` needs to change to `for i in range(N):`. Using `N-1` will skip the last iteration. `0` is also not needed.

```
data = {}
data['platelet'] = [float('nan'),float('nan'),float('nan'),float('nan'),float('nan')]
data['X'] = [1,2,3,4,5]

N = len(data['platelet'])

import math  

for i in range(N):
    if math.isnan(data['platelet'][i]):
        data['platelet'][i] = data['X'][i]
```